# Why doesn't the image element resize to its real proportion under flexbox with object-fit: contain?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, object-fit

I have a container where multiple images will appear in succession (a slide show). Some images are in landscape format, others in portrait. There are also two side panels that should occupy the remaining space on the left and right sides of the image container. Image and side panels have a fixed height, thus the width of the image (and central container) should adjust depending on the proportion of the image. However, I can't make this work.

```css
html,body {
    margin:0;
}
main {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
}
h1 {
    margin:0;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:2em;
}
#divMain {
    background:orange;
    display:flex;
    height:50vh;
    padding:5vh 0;
}
#divBotE,#divBotD {
    background:lime;
    flex:1 0 auto;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    justify-content:space-between;
}
h3 {
    background:black;
    color:white;
    font-size:0.75em;
    text-align:center;
    margin:0 0.5em;
    border-radius:1em;
    padding:0.5em;
}
#divSlides {
    background:white;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    flex:0 1 auto;
}
#imgSlide {
    object-fit:contain;
    height:100%;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<main>
    <h1>Website X</h1>
    <div id='divMain'>
        <div id='divBotE'>
            <h3>Button 1</h3>
            <h3>Button 2</h3>
            <h3>Button 3</h3>
        </div>
        <div id='divSlides'>
            <img id='imgSlide' src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/59/Flor_de_Orqu%C3%ADdea_-_Orchid_Flower.JPG/1280px-Flor_de_Orqu%C3%ADdea_-_Orchid_Flower.JPG' />
        </div>
        <div id='divBotD'>
            <h3>Button 4</h3>
            <h3>Button 5</h3>
            <h3>Button 6</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

As you can see on the snippet, the original image is rather large, making the image object large too, even after resize. The white areas on the sides of the image should be occupied by the green panels. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What result are you trying to achieve? This is what `contain` does - it resizes the whole image to fit within the constraints of the container.

Comment: @FluffyKitten The white areas on the sides of the image should be occupied by the green panels. But it's occupied by the image element, that's why it's white.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you wanting the green panels to get wider if say an image is in portrait mode and to shrink if the image is in landscape so that there is never any white between the left and right sides of an image and the buttons? Or do you want the green buttons to stay the same size but move so they are always touching the sides of an image?

Comment: I think if you set the `background: green` on `#divSlides`, the problem will be solved. Through your description, there is no reason to set the background color to white on slides.

Comment: @AHaworth I want the green panels (and their buttons) to get wider.

Comment: @Derek.W No, it won't. Because the buttons should get wide so as to occupy the remaining space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this where most of the flex-related CSS is removed, with flex-grow set on the buttons divs and the img is given width auto rather than use contain?

```css
html,body {
    margin:0;
}
main {
}
h1 {
    margin:0;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:2em;
}
#divMain {
    background:orange;
    display:flex;
    height:50vh;
    padding:5vh 0;
}
#divBotE,#divBotD {
    background:lime;
    flex-grow: 1;
    float: left;
}
h3 {
    background:black;
    color:white;
    font-size:0.75em;
    text-align:center;
    margin:0 0.5em;
    border-radius:1em;
    padding:0.5em;
}
#divSlides {
    background:pink;
    float:left;
    width:auto;
    height:100%;
}
#imgSlide {
    height:100%;
  width:auto;
}
```

```html
<main>
    <h1>Website X</h1>
    <div id='divMain'>
        <div id='divBotE'>
            <h3>Button 1</h3>
            <h3>Button 2</h3>
            <h3>Button 3</h3>
        </div>
        <div id='divSlides'>
            <img id='imgSlide' src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/59/Flor_de_Orqu%C3%ADdea_-_Orchid_Flower.JPG/1280px-Flor_de_Orqu%C3%ADdea_-_Orchid_Flower.JPG' />
        </div>
        <div id='divBotD'>
            <h3>Button 4</h3>
            <h3>Button 5</h3>
            <h3>Button 6</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Your solution works on Firefox. On Chromium the image is stretched horizontally, and the buttons are compressed on the sides of the screen.

Comment: Ah, I should have tried more browsers, sorry. The image gets stretched on iOS Safari too. I’ll take another look.

Comment: The snippet also works on Edge Windows10 (which is what I was using when I put it up). This is strange as Edge and Chrome are allegedly basically the same under the hood. It even appears to be OK in IE11.

Comment: I have changed the #imgSlide to width auto also and it seems to work on Chrome and IOS Safari now. I was wrong about it working on IE.

Comment: Great! Thank you! Anyway, who cares about IE?

Answer (score 0):

Set the `max-width & max-height` of the image instead of setting `width & height` css attributes.

And set the parent div `display: contents` and it will work.

```css
html,body {
    margin:0;
}
main {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
}
h1 {
    margin:0;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:2em;
}
#divMain {
    background:orange;
    display:flex;
    height:50vh;
    padding:5vh 0;
}
#divBotE,#divBotD {
    background:lime;
    flex:1 0 auto;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    justify-content:space-between;
}
h3 {
    background:black;
    color:white;
    font-size:0.75em;
    text-align:center;
    margin:0 0.5em;
    border-radius:1em;
    padding:0.5em;
}
#divSlides {
    background:white;
    display: contents;
}
#imgSlide {
  object-fit: contain;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<main>
    <h1>Website X</h1>
    <div id='divMain'>
        <div id='divBotE'>
            <h3>Button 1</h3>
            <h3>Button 2</h3>
            <h3>Button 3</h3>
        </div>
        <div id='divSlides'>
            <img id='imgSlide' src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/59/Flor_de_Orqu%C3%ADdea_-_Orchid_Flower.JPG/1280px-Flor_de_Orqu%C3%ADdea_-_Orchid_Flower.JPG' />
        </div>
        <div id='divBotD'>
            <h3>Button 4</h3>
            <h3>Button 5</h3>
            <h3>Button 6</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Your snippet looks exactly like mine when running.

Comment: Checking the image in developer tools, when you select the image, you can see that the image has no `white space`. The white background is made by the div `#divSlides`. @Rodrigo

Comment: Ok, I saw it. But 1) why don't `flex:0 1 auto;` made `#divSlides` shrink? 2) It's not a solution yet, since the buttons should enlarge and get close to the image.

Comment: It seems to work, except for the message on the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display): "This is an experimental API that should not be used in production code."